# Add listener jDateChooser

Tags: java, listener, jdatechooser

i haved create this metod for add listeners in my dataChooser.

```
 public final void añadirEsccuhaDataChoser() {
    jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener((PropertyChangeEvent e) -> {
        if ("date".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
            listarviajes1();
        }
    });
    this.add(jDateChooser1);
}
```

but the result who i have obtened after run the project is this.

[datachooser moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V69L1.png)

but the my original desing is this.

[data chooser original position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zczC.png)

the method i haved situate into the `public vReservas().`

[situation method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7MSC.png)

What can I do to prevent the dataChooser from moving?

this is a solution.
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHbub.png)

Comment: Sorry to disturb, but i discovery the solution.
I haved edited the internal code for my dataChooser and the problem has solve. in internal code i added the listener.nd the problem has solve. In internal code i added the listener.

Comment: You may want to write that as an answer to your own question.  Provide the modified code that fixed it and explain what was wrong.  This could help somebody else with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I created a method, instead of adding the listener in the JdateChooser's internal code.

The code to add the listener is the same, just place it in the custom code option of the jDateChooser.

[the ubication of listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5mZm.png)